# Cannot sort array as per key value using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I need to sort `json` array as per the key value using PHP. I am providing my code below.

```
$detailsArr = array(
    array('name' => 'Bob',    'active' => 1),
    array('name' => 'Rachel', 'active' => 0),
    array('name' => 'Arthur', 'active' => 0),
    array('name' => 'Paige',  'active' => 1),
    array('name' => 'Chris',  'active' => 0),
);
```

Here I need those having `active=1` those will come first. Here is my code:

```
function sortByActive($a, $b){
      $a = $a['active'];
      $b = $b['active'];

      if ($a == $b)
        {
           return 0;
        }

     return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}
usort($detailsArr, 'sortByActive');
```

Here I am expecting the output like below.

```
$detailsArr = array(
        array('name' => 'Bob',    'active' => 1),
        array('name' => 'Paige',  'active' => 1),
        array('name' => 'Rachel', 'active' => 0),
        array('name' => 'Arthur', 'active' => 0),
        array('name' => 'Chris',  'active' => 0),
    );
```

But as per my code I could not get the expected value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `return` line like below:-

```
return ($a < $b) ?  1 : -1;
```

Output:- https://eval.in/833885